# How do I wait the end of XMLHttpRequest to redirect user in another page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a web site that respect a RESTful service, in html page called *signup.html* where the user can sign up in web site. I would redirect the user in the home page of site after the sign up is complete. How do I wait the end of XMLHttpRequest and the operations with the database from the php page associated with *signup.html* to redirect user in this another page?

**My javascript code in signup.html is:**

```
<script>
  window.onload = bindEvents;

  function bindEvents(){
    //when the button with id="post" is clicked call a function userInsert
    document.getElementById("post").addEventListener("click", userInsert); 
  }

  function userInsert(){
    var data = {};
    data.nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    data.cognome = document.getElementById("cognome").value;
    data.nascita = document.getElementById("nascita").value;
    data.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    data.password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var repassword = $("#repassword").val();  //get value of 'repeat password' to verify the correct insert

    if(data.password == repassword) {
      var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
      var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oReq.onload = function(){document.getElementById("ajaxres").innerHTML = oReq.responseText;};
      oReq.open("post", "api_signup.php/utente/", true);
      oReq.send(jsondata);
    } else {
      var passElem = document.getElementById("password");
      var repassElem = document.getElementById("repassword");
      passElem.className += " is-invalid";
      repassElem.className += " is-invalid";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You've already got an `onload` handler, that should be called when the request is done? Just do your redirect there?

Comment: I would suggest that you use jquery to execute the `post` request and just redirect the user on the callback.

Comment: @GregSchmidt no, the onload in page return a text "okay" to verify if the signup was finished with success

Comment: But that only happens at "the end of XMLHttpRequest and the operations with the database", so why isn't it exactly the appropriate place to do your redirect?

Comment: @GregSchmidt okay, thanks. So I insert the link on the other page into '.onload' for the redirect